# Is there a maximum number of classes / labels that you can use in Stanford Named Entity Recognizer's CRFClassifier?

Tags: stanford-nlp

Is there a maximum number of classes you can use in Stanford’s NER CRFClassifier?

And is there any consequences when you go up to about 100 000 different classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a strong knowledge of CRF's so I could be wrong about this, but this paper:

http://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/tcohn/papers/cohn06ecml.pdf

says that training time grows quadratically with respect to the number of classes.  Also if you are building a model with 100,000 classes, you would want substantially more than the 200,000 tokens used to generate the 4-class NER model.

I believe that would lead to a training time measured in centuries or eons!